# Alert popup box before uploading/selecting file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Is it possible to alert a popup box with some information before selecting a file?
I have a input of file type and clicking it will open file explorer of OS to select file and upload it, which is normal behaviour. But I want to show a piece of information using alert before "File explorer" comes into play.

I tried using angular click function on input but it didn't work.

```
<input type="file" (click)="alert('Some information')" />
```

Comment: Sorry it was very silly, instead of using angular click function the DOM "onclick" event worked!

Comment: Use javascript DOM object for this instead of angular

Comment: I dont find your answer. so you can use custom input button next to input file.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('btnFile').onclick = function() {
    alert('Some information')
    document.getElementById('FileUpload').click();
};
```

```css
#FileUpload {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="FileUpload">
<input type="button" id="btnFile" value="Upload">
```